# How to store files or images on the file system?

Tags: file, data-storage

I am working on project -online file management where we have to tore file and images.so we are in confusion state that whether we use file system or database to store file and images;;;;;

Comment: What database are you planning to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An usual approach is to store big binary data (e.g. images) in files, and put pointers to them in a database. This way the best of both worlds can be combined (to a degree, at least); file system's efficiency of file storage, and database's search / sort / lookup capabilities.

Answer (score -1):

Keep your files out of the database.  Create a record in the database like so:

```
 primaryKey   FileName    FileDescription     OnDiskKeyName 
 ------------ ----------- ------------------- -----------------
```

use a UUID to give a unique name to the file, and a link to the database with a human-readable name.